# How to switch between Service Locator and DI Container in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, service-locator

Zend Framework 2 provides the developer with both -- a `Dependency Injection Container` and a `Service Locator` implementation. I've always used the `Service Locator`. Now I would like to try the `Dependency Injector`, but don't see, how to switch to it. There is no `bootstrap` file anymore like in ZF1 and I have also not found anything about it in the configs. How does it work?

Comment: It's perhaps a little thin on DI; however the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.di.quick-start.html#zend-di-quickstart) is a good place to start.

Comment: The ZF2 docu is generally very good, but I have not found an answer to this question there.

Comment: "*How* does it work" is explained in the docs so I think your question is a little vague on what you are stuck with. Update your question with something a little more specific.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but have you seen the note at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.di.introduction.html It states: Unless you have specific needs for a dependency injection container versus more general Inversion of Control, we recommend using Zend\ServiceManager for the above reasons.

Comment: I've read many times that `Zend\Di` is deprecated in favor of `Zend\ServiceManager` but I can't find a link right now.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli That's a good point. Thank you! As I know, `Zend\Di` is not deperecated. But `Zend\ServiceManager` is actually the better choice in the most cases.

Comment: @AlexP Well, you're right -- "How it works" might be another question. But anyway, I want to know, where is defined, whether the `Zend\Di` or `Zend\ServiceManager` is used, and how to switch between these two approaches. Since it should be a bootstrap/config thing and I could not find anything about it in the configs.

Comment: well you can use both of them in tandem; just add the config under `di` or create the required services `onBootstrap`; there is no need to 'switch' between the two. However, as far as I can tell, doing so could add some ambiguity when you request the service as you would first need to fetch the DI container from the service manager `$serviceManager->get('di')`. As mentioned previously by @Ruben, unless you have a specific use case for using `Zend\Di` I would stick with the ServiceManager.